About CloudKit Security Roles and Permissions
I've checked that there are some questions like mine. But the terminology seems to have changed and it's been time, so I opened a new question.

Hi, I'm trying to add the ability to back up and record data to iCloud using CloudKit.
Here's what I'm unsure about:
I understand that the 'CloudKit Dashboard' has 'Security Roles'. I thought these were meant to set permissions for accessing and modifying users' data, but I found there was no change even when I removed all 'Permissions' from 'Default Roles'.

I'd like to know what _world, _icloud, and _creator in Default Roles mean respectively.

I would like to know what changes the creation, read, and write permissions make.

Is it better to just use the default settings?


Here's what I understand so far:
Default Roles:

_world: I don't know
_icloud: An account that is not my device but is linked to my iCloud
_creator: My Device

(If I look it up, other people have 'Authenticated', but I have 'icloud'.)
Permissions:

create: Create data
read: Read data
write: Update and delete data.

I'm not sure if I understand this correctly.
